# Angular 6: don't trigger validators setValue

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm building a CRUD app using `Angular 6.`

My forms are used for adding and updating items. When the user updates an item, the form is pre-populated from the server. When the server updates the form it triggers the validation.

How can I update the form values without triggering the validation?

Here is the relevant code:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required], MyAsyncValidator],
        comments: [''],
    });

    this.http.get('/api')
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.form.setValue({ name: data.name, comments: data.comments });
        });
    //How to populate form without triggering validation
}
```

The template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input formControlName="name"
            class="form-control"
            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': isInvalid(form.controls.name)}"
            type="text">
        <small *ngIf="form.get('name').status=='PENDING'" class="form-text text-muted">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Checking Name...
        </small>
        <small class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].hasError('required')">Name Required</div>
            <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].hasError('exists')">Name Exists</div>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this is either a bug in angular or some weird behaviors implemented in the code. I had the same issue and debugged through the source code only to find this:

setValue will call to updateValueAndValidity(): https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/39c8baea318e740111b1c748718c3203a61b4cdf/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L941

and in updateValueAndValidity(), it calls asyncValidatior:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/39c8baea318e740111b1c748718c3203a61b4cdf/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L554

My impression is that when setting `emitEvent: false`, no validation should be triggered, however, this is not the case. What is even weirder is the fact that no matter if you set `updateOn` to `change` or `blur` the asyncValidator will be triggered on setValue.

I have no option but to remove asyncValidator before every setValue call and add it back afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I also found that validation runs regardless. I found that when the form is created with formbuilder the validation always runs but even if the validation fails the form remains valid on first run. So I ended up putting a check in my async validator that assumes if control is not dirty then it is the first validation call... if (!control.dirty) {return of(null)}, this prevents needless calls to server..

Answer (score 3):

Just faced same problem.

Calling `control.markAsTouched()` before calling `control.setValue(value)` worked for my case.

Does this mean validation fails only when the control is touched? hm...

I'm using Angular 7 btw

Answer (score 0):

Why u are doing `setValue`??

I recommend you to bind values when you get response. If response will be null or empty it will be blank otherwise it will populate values.

Code:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.http.get('/api')
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
       this.form = this.fb.group({
             name: [data.name || '', [Validators.required], MyAsyncValidator],
             comments: [data.comments || ''],
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Because I don't want to call the server needlessly if I know they are adding an item..but it gave me an idea to try

Comment: But your code will also call the server once, So does mine!

Comment: Not if I check the url params for an id, if id exist call server, if not create blank form

Comment: well I tried using what you recommended and as soon as the form is created, does n't matter which way the values are set, the validation including the async is called. Thanks for the ideas though

Answer (score 0):

To give a code answer to @zokland's answer, I did something similar but removed and added back the validator itself rather than clear all validators:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

export const MyAsyncValidator = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  control.removeValidators(MyAsyncValidator);
  control.setValue(control.value);
  control.addValidators(MyAsyncValidator);
  return null;
}
```

This lets you use validators as a way to modify the form value as it's being input, without a bunch of calls, as well as not needing to store its current validators to then be added after the `setValue()` call.

Answer (score -2):

Try updating them individually.

```
this.form.controls.name.setValue(data.name);
this.form.controls.comments.setValue(data.comments);
```

Use this in HTML for async validator:

```
<small class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].hasError('required')">Name Required</div>
    <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].touched && form.controls['name'].hasError('exists')">Name Exists</div>
</small>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried it and it still calls my asyncvalidator...

Comment: Can you please add the html for validation message used for async validator?

Comment: is 'exists' your async validation? See the updated answer.